# Python - how to update list indicies

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Pseudo code:

```
data = []
data.append({'name': 'John', 'age': '37'})
data.append({'name': 'Joe', 'age': '25'})
```

Here I do some calculations and I want to update data[0], in order to get:

```
data[0] = {'name': 'John', 'age': '37', 'country': 'USA'}
```

How can I update that first index of list?

Comment: `data.insert(0, {'name': 'John', 'age': '37, 'country': 'USA'})`?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: @leaf That's perfection right there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like:

```
data[0]['country'] = 'USA' # if you want to set value of country only
```

or

```
data[0] = {'name': 'John', 'age': '37', 'country': 'USA'} # if you want to update whole dictionary
```